# How to call in validation logic in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Trying to figure out how to call in validation logic in a ruby program.
I can not figure out what I am missing.  This program is intended for use in the console.

```
require_relative 'main_support'

prompt = ">> "
  puts "Username/Password Validator"

begin
  print "Please enter your Username: ", prompt
  username = gets.chomp
rescue
    puts "Oops! You must enter a valid Username! Please try again."
  end
begin
  print "Please enter your Password: ", prompt
  password = gets.chomp
rescue
 puts "Oops! You must enter a valid password! Please try again."
end

# Decides if the Username and Password is 'true' or 'false'

if (username == true) && (password == true)
  puts "The Username/Password combination is valid!" "\n" 
# else 
#   puts "Sorry! Please try again later!!" "\n"
end

puts "Thank you for trying the Username/Password Validator! \n"
```

Below is the main_support.rb file.

```
def username
  @username
end

class Username_validator
  def username_validation(username, *args)
    validate :username    
    has_one_letter = username =~ /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,20}$/
    t_valid_char = username =~ /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,20}$/
    validates_exclusion_of /^?=.*\z$/
    errors.add(:username, "Oops! Username must have at least one letter     
    and contain only letters and numbers") unless (has_one_letter and        
    t_valid_char)
  end
end

class Password_validator
  def password_validation(password, *args)
    validate :password    
    has_one_letter = password =~ /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,20}$/
    t_valid_char = password =~ /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,20}$/
    validates_exclusion_of  :username ⇒ "Must not match username"
    validates_exclusion_of /^?=.*\z$/
    errors.add(:password, "Oops! Password must have at least one letter 
    and contain only letters and numbers.") unless (has_one_letter and 
    t_valid_char)
  end
end

def validate_password(password)

end
```

Here is one of the errors that I am receiving from the console:

```
main_support.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting   
keyword_end (SyntaxError)
validates_exclusion_of  :username ⇒ "Must not match username"
```

My code is not enforcing any of the validations because the validation logic written is never being called.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Indentation, while not absolutely required in Ruby scripts, is still a very good idea. It shows blocks and helps us understand loops. Please indent your code correctly in your question, and make sure you maintain that in your own code. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: Also, please describe why your code isn't doing what you want. Provide sample inputs and what you'd expect to happen. See "[ask]".

Comment: beyond that you have a ton of issues such as you are trying to use rails validations outside of ActiveRecord without any reference to them e.g. what do you think happens when you call `validate :password` or `errors.add(:username)` you will need methods for these to work. I am not even sure how to help because what you have done is purely conceptual (At a very high level) from what I can see and will never function as it stands.